# Create tensorflow with tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices and one property with dynamic size

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I have a pandas dataframe and of its columns is "bbox" with value i.e. `[[94.0, 58.0, 469.0, 362.0]]`. I want to convert this dataframe to a custom dataset with tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices.
I want the bbox element to have a shape of (None,4) but it is created with shape (1,4) `tf.Tensor([[ 94.  58. 469. 362.]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)` and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

My dataset is created with this code:

```
myimages = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(train_data).to_dict("list")
myimages = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(myimages)
```

Thanks everyone in advance for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `tf.data.Dataset.map` and `tf.squeeze` to get rid of the extra dimension:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

train_data = {'names': ['some_image.jpg', 'other_image.jpg'],
              'bbox': [[[94.0, 58.0, 469.0, 362.0]], [[94.0, 58.0, 469.0, 362.0]]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(train_data)
myimages = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df['names'].to_numpy(), df['bbox'].to_list()))
myimages = myimages.map(lambda x, y: (x, tf.squeeze(y, axis=0)))

for x, y in myimages:
  print(x, y)
```

```
tf.Tensor(b'some_image.jpg', shape=(), dtype=string) tf.Tensor([ 94.  58. 469. 362.], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(b'other_image.jpg', shape=(), dtype=string) tf.Tensor([ 94.  58. 469. 362.], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It certainly works and it is accepted as more thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the tensor is `(1, 4)` since the `bbox` column in your dataframe contains elements that are a list of lists, not a single list.

To get a shape of `(4, )` for each label, you can modify the elements in the `bbox` column in your dataframe by indexing each bbox element to obtain the first bbox, and inserting it into the dataframe like so:

```
myimages["bbox"] = [bbox_element[0] for bbox_element in myimages["bbox"].values]
```